# Createing reference with NuGet in Azure Devops

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget-package

I create a NuGet package and publish it to a feed in Azure Devops.

When consuming it a dependent dll wasen't included, it dosen't exist as a NuGet package so i can't fix it like that.

i changed the csproj and added it like described [here](https://dev.to/julianchu/c-including-3rd-dll-file-to-nuget-package-4idc).

Now i get the dll, but not added as a Reference. Is that possible to fix in Azure Devops?

Comment: Hi @berinder did you get a change to try out below workarounds, how did it go?

Comment: I added it manually, like you suggested in the first alternativ. 

The second alternative feels cleaner, but i haven't come around to that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you packedd the dependent dll with your NuGet package. When the NuGet package is consumed by your project, the dependent dll will exist in `..\packages\{yourNugetPackage}\lib\{targetFramework}\dependent.dll`.

So you can manually add a Reference in your project to this dependent dll. For below example.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DependentDll">
          <HintPath>..\packages\yourNugetPackage.1.0.0\lib\netcoreapp2.0\dependent.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Another possible workaround is that you can try creating another Nuget package for this dependent dll and publish it to the feed in azure devops.

Then add [dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element) to this package in your original Nuget package project and republish  to feed in Azure Devops. So that the dependent dll can be managed with your original Nuget Package. See below simple example.

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>sample</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <authors>Microsoft</authors>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency id="dependentDllPackage" version="1.0.0" />
         </dependencies>
    </metadata>
</package>
```